# JQuery auto complete with links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, pdo

I'm in the process of establishing a website which uses JQuery's auto complete to give users suggestions on pages. I store the page ID and title in a SQL database (connecting using PDO). At the moment, I've got the auto complete feature working, however, I am absolutely stumped on how to get the  auto complete list to turn into clickable links which direct the user to the relevant page based off the page ID in the database.

**Here's my search.php file**

```
    <?php
require('includes/connect.class.php');
if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $return_arr = array();
        try {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, locationName FROM locations WHERE locationsName LIKE :term');
                $stmt->execute(array(
                        'term' => '%' . $_GET['term'] . '%'
                ));
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                        $return_arr[] = $row['locationName'];
                }
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
?>
```

**and my JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $(".locationlist").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 1
    });            
});
```

**The database looks like this**

```
Locations
|---ID---||---locationName---|
|   1    ||       Test1      |
|   2    ||       Test2      |
 ----------------------------
```

I've done some research, and I believe I need to modify JQuery to display an array of objects. I'm not too sure how to do this.

What would be the best way to  have my auto complete list get the page ID from the SQL database and become clickable links?

Comment: what is this `$(function locationsearch() {`

Comment: Sorry @JqueryKing, it was just an excerpt from my functions file. I've updated my question to save confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need for clickable links there. You can redirect the page within the autocomplete's [`select` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) , where you have access to the selected `item` object:

> - **`ui`** (Type: Object):
>
>   - **`item`** (Type: Object):
>
>     - An Object with **`label`** and **`value`** properties for the selected option.

---

`ui.item.value` will be the page ID generated with your PHP

```
$(".locationlist").autocomplete({
    source : "search.php",
    minLength: 1,
    select : function(event, ui){
        // You may need to change this part, as I don't know the exact values:
        location.href = "http://your-site.com/" + ui.item.value;
    }
});
```

---

As for your PHP, you can modify the output array like so:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $return_arr[] = array(
        'value' => $row['ID'],
        'label' => $row['locationName']
    );
}
```

Comment: Do you know of any way to stop the ID number from displaying in the text area while the page redirects?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what *textarea* you're reffering to. You may need to show your HTML and the whole code.

Comment: Sorry, the search box where the user types in the search query. When the user clicks on the desired result, the ID number is displayed in the search box

Comment: Try to reverse the `$return_arr[]` array (set first `label` and then `value`)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I'm having a mess around with the code. I think I need to add a hidden text box to store the page ID. I'll report back if I'm successful.